# Flutter : Update Google Maps SDK on iOS from 3.9.0 to 4.1.0.0

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I added Google Maps service in my app 4/5 days ago because I need only to get the user's position.
My problem is that when I open the page with the `GoogleMap` widget I receive this error code :

```
Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 3.9.0.0
New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 4.1.0.0
```

And the widget is grey with `Google` on its bottom-left corner and the position icon on the bottom-right.

I tried to update using : `pod repo update` and adding this line in Podfile :
`pod 'GoogleMaps', '4.1.0.0'`

But I still have the same error, I took a look on the internet but I only found old methods.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Have you tried to use the latest package google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6? It uses 4.1.0 by default although the latest version is now is 5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

have to added the google map key to the IOS folder? you can also try updating the package version in pubspec.yaml  for the google maps

Comment: " google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6 " on pubspec.yaml and devs site. Google maps key already added, I have to update the sdk.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the google_maps_flutter package have a constraint to use a version lower than 3.10.0 so you need to wait to an update of the package.

I found that in this github issue:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63530